# Does synchronizing on a thread safe object block other calls that might manipulate it?

Tags: java, concurrency

Suppose I create a thread safe object:

```
PriorityBlockingQueue<Object> safeQueue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<Object>();
```

If I synchronize on it:

```
synchronized (safeQueue) {
   ....
}
```

Does code that block:

```
// some non-synchronized block
Object value = safeQueue.poll();
```

Comment: `synchronized` and thread-safe objects have _nothing_ to do with each-other.

Comment: @SLaks I could make an object thread-safe using synchronized, yeah?

Comment: @SLaks: Not true. If the object is internally synchronized on `this`, then you could be in trouble if you lock the object from the outside.

Comment: @Tudor: Properly-written thread-safe objects do not lock on `this`.

Comment: @SLaks: If only all thread-safe objects were "properly written"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  The only time you get *any* blocking is if another thread is *also* doing a `synchronized` on the same object.  If your code is `synchronized (safeQueue)` then a call to `PriorityBlockingQueue.poll()` would only block if `poll()` was a `synchronized` method or if the code used `synchronized (this)` code.

When you call `safeQueue.poll()` the `PriorityBlockingQueue` code is actually using an internal  `ReentrantLock`, and *not* doing a `synchronized (this)`.  Here's the code for `poll()`:

```
public E poll() {
    final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
    lock.lock();
    try {
        return q.poll();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Lastly, as you mention, `PriorityBlockingQueue` is already reentrant so you do not need to synchronize on it to allow multiple threads to access the queue.  You could still need to synchronize on it if you needed to solve race conditions in your own code of course.

Comment: Doesn't the poll() operation have to do some sort of synchronization on the object in order to guarantee thread safety?

Comment: Sure but that is handled internal to the object @Ben.  You cannot assume that it works by calling `synchronized (this)`.  I've edited my answer to show what the `poll()` method locks.

Comment: I figured it was doing something other than synchronized(this) but thought there might be some overlap. Thanks for taking the time to explain it!

Comment: Sure.  Yeah, there is no "overlap".  Either you are `synchronized` on the same object or you are not.  Or you are using the same `ReentrantLock` or other lock structure.

Comment: And indeed, as a more general rule of thumb, 'synchronized' locks are an independent method of locking/synchronisation to Java 5 concurrency utilities such as blocking queues, latches, Locks etc.

Comment: @Gray You can't assume it _doesn't_ call `synchronized(this)`, either. `Thread` is an example of a thread-safe class that does that, so trying to synchronize on it can get you into trouble. I think one of the Java Puzzlers puzzles uses that quirk, actually.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: it depends on where the thread-safe class's thread safety comes from.

You have to depend on the class's documentation, or its implementation code if you want to go down that route (beware of changes in future versions...), or be defensive and not trust it, instead synchronizing on another object for your atomicity needs (or whatever else you're synchronizing for).

It certainly doesn't have to block, especially as many of the `java.util.concurrent` classes are non-blocking (and thus don't synchronize on themselves to achieve thread safety). On the other hand, if the class gets its thread safety from `synchronized(this)` (or, equivalently, `synchronized` instance methods), then yes, that'll block. An example of this is the map returned from `Collections.synchronizedMap`, in which that blocking is documented and is actually an intended feature (so that you can atomically query and modify the map).

Comment: I ended up using the Collections synchronized methods to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if the object itself has methods that are synchronized on the instance. For example:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
synchronized(c) {
    ...
}
```

and `MyClass` is:

```
class MyClass {

    // foo needs a lock on this
    public synchronized void foo() { 
       ...
    }
}
```

Now, a call to `c.foo();` outside of a `synchronized` section will still block if it's executed in parallel with the code written above.

For example, the old Java `Vector` class was synchronized internally like this, so locking on the object from the outside could interfere with the internal locking.